# List indices must be integers on two dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
    ret = {}
    machs = self.machines_db(**kwargs)

    for mach in machs:
        ret[mach['name']] = mach
```

`machs` is a list of dictionaries, and each dictionary definitely contains a 'name' element.

So, `ret` and `mach` are both dictionaries. So why am I getting:

> list indices must be integers, not str

on the last line when I try to run this code? The other questions I've turned up with this error message have all had a list being queried with a string.

Thank you!

Comment: Because it's not a dictionary.

Comment: You're wrong about the type of some object involved.

Comment: What is your evidence that `machs` is a list of dictionaries?

Comment: `print type(machs), set(map(type, machs))` and show us what that prints.

Comment: I'm printing it out in the log while I try to debug it.

Comment: Thanks user2357112! It turns out there are a couple empty lists that snuck their way into machs.